# Só uma parte do valor de um input

Tags: javascript

Bom dia,

Estou querendo pegar só uma parte do valor de um `input`.

Ex:

```
<input type="text" value="João Paulo Silva" id="nome" />

var nome = $("#nome").text();
```

E trazer o seguinte resultado:

```
joao.silva
```

Se alguém souber fico muito agradecido.

Comment: Já tentou `var nome = $("#nome").val().split(" "); alert(nome[0]); alert(nome[nome.length-1]);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando que seu `input` seja:

```
<input type="text" value="João Paulo Silva" id="nome" />
```

Você pode retornar o nome no formato especificado na pergunta usando a função no código abaixo.

A função irá descartar os nomes do meio (bem como partes do nome, como *"de"*, *"do"*, *"dos"*, *"da"*, *"das"* e *"e"*, ex.: *João Paulo **da** Silva*), pegar apenas o primeiro e último nomes e concatenar um ponto "." no meio dos dois, além de converter tudo para minúscula e eliminar possíveis acentuações:

```js
function nomeAbrev(){

   var nome = $("#nome").val().toLowerCase();

   var reg_ex = "/ de | do | dos | da | das | e /i";
   
   nome = nome.replace(reg_ex," ").split(" ");
   nome = nome.shift()+"."+nome.pop();

   var acentos = "ãáàâäéèêëíìîïõóòôöúùûüç";
   var sem_acentos = "aaaaaeeeeiiiiooooouuuuc";

   for(var x=0; x<nome.length; x++){
      var str_pos = acentos.indexOf(nome.substr(x,1));
      if(str_pos != -1){
         nome = nome.replace(acentos.charAt(str_pos),sem_acentos.charAt(str_pos));
      }
   }

   console.log(nome);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="João Paulo Silva" id="nome" />
<br />
<input type="button" value="Clique para Converter" onclick="nomeAbrev()" />
```

Comment: Funcionou, isso mesmo que eu precisava. Muito obrigado